# Failure to copy in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am executing the same batch file on 4 systems. This file perform command line McAfee scan and at the end it copies scan log file to remote shared folder. 2 PC's are Win7 and 2 are WinXP. I'm not sure if it's OS issue but copy works always on Win7 but failed on WinXP.
In case it failed to copy on WinXP I go prompt and perform copy command manually it worked but I need that it would be done using batch. 
Any suggestion what could cause the issue?
Could it be that 'copy' behavious differently on XP v.s. Win7?
Or something else .. like timing issue ...?
Thanks in advance ..
Note: LogFolder for each PC is different
Here is my batch:

```
REM Perform a Full scan and log result


if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" (
    set "PATH_=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise"
    set SHUTDOWN=shutdown /s /f
) else (
    set "PATH_=%ProgramFiles%\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise"
    set SHUTDOWN=shutdown -s -f
)

set LOGDIR=C:\McAfee
set DIR=\\xyz\LogFolder\


"%PATH_%\scan32.exe" /Task {ED73BEB7-1E8F-45AC-ABBC-A749AF6E2710}      %* /ANALYZE /MANY /ALL /CLEAN /DAM /NC /NOEXPIRE /PLAD /PROGRAM /SUB /STREAMS /UNZIP /THREADS=4 /TIMEOUT=15 /APPEND  /AUTOEXIT 

start /B copy %LOGDIR%\OnDemandScanLog.txt   /Y "%DIR%"


REM start %SHUTDOWN%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the "start /B ". 
Put a PAUSE on the next line after the copy command so you can see any error messages. it might be a permissions problem or a location that does not exist.

Comment: thanks for reply. Are you suggesting to remove "start /B" at all and leave only 'copy'? OK, I could try that. Well ... I could put PAUSE but since this is batch file and 'copy' would fail I wouldn't see anything IMO. It can't be permission or location issue because after batch completed and failed to copy ... I run 'copy' command from the prompt pointing to the same location and it worked. In other words .. it always work from prompt but failed from batch .. Not sure ... could it be timing issue ?...

Comment: Yes... remove "start /B" and leave only 'copy'. PAUSE will stop and wait for you to "Press any key to continue'. This will leave any error messages for you  to see.  You should always check for errors anyway; maybe change your copy statement to something like this. copy /Y "%LOGDIR%\OnDemandScanLog.txt" "%DIR%" || (COLOR CF & PAUSE & COLOR 07)

Comment: I found that 'copy' issue was related to my destination server settings. As long as I changed destination 'copy' command didn't cause any problem